# Square root function on complex plane and on $S^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

If we let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be given by $f(z)=z^2$, then writing $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta = \arg(z)$ and $r=|z|$, we have that $f(z)=r^2 e^{i(2\theta)}$. In that case, let $a \in \mathbb{C}$, then we can also write $a$ in polar form as $a = R(\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)$. Now, if we think, which $z$ gives $f(z)=a$, it's easy to come out with $z=r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}$. The only problem is that if we also pick $z = r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2+\pi}$ then it'll also do the job since $\cos$ and $\sin$ have period $2\pi$. In other words, $|f^{-1}(a)|> 1$ and so, we have problem on defining the inverse function.

Now, I've heard that using the sphere $S^2$ we can solve the problem. My idea was: if we construct $\mathbb{C}$ simply as $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a product, then if we forget the product, $\mathbb{C}$ is just $\mathbb{R}^2$. In that case, let $N \in S^2$ be the north pole and let $U = S^2 \setminus \{N\}$, then we know we can construct a chart for $S^2$ using stereographic projection, mapping $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is essentially $\mathbb{R}^2$, my idea was to consider the same chart, $(x,U)$ but with $x: U \to \mathbb{C}$.

In that case my idea was "now we transfer the $f(z)=z^2$ function to $U\subset S^2$ and show that the version of this function there satisfies $|f^{-1}(a)|=1$ for every $a \in U$ and we'll be able to define the square root", what I did was to construct $\xi : U \to U$ by $\xi = x^{-1} \circ f \circ x$, so it takes a point on the sphere, maps to $\mathbb{C}$, takes the square, and maps back to the sphere. Now, a mathematician I know said this won't work, and $\xi$ will still have the same problem, and that indeed $S^2$ cannot solve the problem.

Isn't this the way we use $S^2$ to solve the problem to define the square root? How can we do so then? Is it true that $S^2$ don't solve this problem?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You may be confusing the sphere with a two sheeted Riemann surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The squaring function is no more one-to-one on the sphere than on the plane.  In other words, to define a square-root function on the sphere you need to choose between two possible values just as on the plane.  You wrote "I've heard that using the sphere $S^2$ we can solve the problem". Whoever told you this either meant something quite different (perhaps talking about a different problem?) or was simply wrong.  (I can't think of what other problem (s)he might have meant, so my guess is it's an error.)